# Mapping 4 tables in Entity Framework using Fluent API

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am having difficulties in creating custom mapping table in EF6.

I have 4 tables:

- Student
- Instructor
- Questions
- Course

What I want is to create a table that will include all primary keys of those 4 tables and add a score column to it.

What is the command that should I use in Entity Framework Fluent API?

This is the classes that i have created

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Instructor
{
    public Instructor()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Instructors = new HashSet<Instructor>();
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does the score refer to each single question or to the complete result for the course? Another point: In my opinion the instructor is a property of the course. So in your table with the "Score" value you should only have foreign keys to "Course" and "Student", is this correct?

Comment: no sir. each of them are separate objects.. Is it possible to map a 4 table to 1 table... What i want is to have a table that compose of the following column: StudentID, InstructorID, CourseID, QuestionID, Score where 4 id came from 4 separate tables.... I am planning to create an instructor evaluation system.... Tnx